# OOM Error in Apache beam java streaming pipeline

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, google-cloud-spanner

My dataflow job streaming pipeline is designed as below.

1. Reading updated/inserted row from spanner change stream as datachangerecord
2. if datachangerecord mod is insert than create tablerow
3. if datachangerecord mod is update than collect primary key as Pcollection ( because i need complete row to insert in GBQ, datachangerocord newJson only giving me updated columns. not all columns)
4. apply GroupIntoBatches of 5000 size with MaxBufferingDuration as 5000ms on the update key value Pcollection
   This will split my update Pcollection into batches, each batch contain 5000 keys.
5. calling spanner again using spanner DatabaseClient here  iam using `In` query so that for 5000 update keys it will make single spanner call
6. Than creating tablerow for spanner update resultset.
7. flattening both insert tablerow ( from step 2 )and update table row into single pcollection
8. publish to pubsub topic for both update and insert tablerow
9. writing both update and insert tablerow  into GBQ

This is a streaming job here iam getting OOM becouse of spanner update calls ( if i remove steps 3 to 6 no OOM )

job profiler giving the below traces

[image]

from profiler `java arrays copyofrange`  occupies more memory and below is job log

`generic::unknown: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:`

1. How can I solve this error?
2. Is there any way to get complete row from spanner change stream, so that I can avoid spanner call?

Comment: On what operating system is the application running?

Comment: "os.name": "Windows 11","os.version": "10.0",

Comment: Your problem is identified by `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread`. Your options are to select a larger instance size [link](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/troubleshoot-oom#increase-memory) or optimize [link](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/troubleshoot-oom#optimize)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As what @John Hanley said, `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread` can be resolved by optimizing your pipeline by reducing the memory usage, and by alotting more memory available on workers or per thread.

Also, refer to this [Dataflow pipeline diagram](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/troubleshoot-oom#resolve-errors) to visualize the troubleshooting workflow .

[image]